# PHP MySQL Upload image linked with all properties using form

Tags: php, html, sql, database, xampp

This is my form code to add new product to my table 'items' in database.

```
                <form method="post" action="additem.php">
                    Product name: <input method="text" name="itemName" class="field">
                    Size: <select name="sizes" class="field">
                        <option value="XS">XS</option>
                        <option value="S">S</option>
                        <option value="M">M</option>
                        <option value="L">L</option>
                        <option value="XL">XL</option>
                    </select>
                    Gender: <select name="gender" class='field'>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        <option value="Kids">Kids clothing</option>
                    </select>
                    Price: <input method="text" name="price" class="field">
                    Image: 'Your code here'
                    <input type="submit" class="btn">
                </form>
```

Php code to insert data from form to table 'items'. User enters all properties of item to be added and should upload image file. When user clicks submit button the php code will process.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'onlinestorebd');
$itemName=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['itemName']);
$itemSize=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['sizes']);
$price=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['price']);
$gender=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['gender']);
$itemPhoto=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['itemPhoto']);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "onlinestorebd");
$qq="INSERT INTO items (itemName, sizes, gender, price, itemPhoto) VALUES ('".$itemName."','".$itemSize."', '".$gender."', '".$price."','".$itemPhoto."')";
$result=$mysqli->query($qq);




mysqli_close($mysqli);



IF(!$result){
    echo "Data insert failed <br><br>";
    echo mysql_error();
    
} ELSE {

    echo "Item has been added";
    echo "<br><br><a href=\"editdb.php\">Back to products list</a>";
    
}

?>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the question is here. I can see the `Image: 'Your code here'` - are you expecting others to add the necessary HTML input element and then code the upload process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have to add a parameter for image with form element.

Your Code

```
<form method="post" action="additem.php">
```

New Code

```
 <form method="post" action="additem.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then check your php.ini file

```
file_uploads = On
```

And last step

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `getimagesize ` is not recommended to verify it is an image. `Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. ` Also there is more the user will need to do

Comment: My advices are just basic steps.